# Nothing shows up on console after powering coral dev board

Tags: google-coral

I have been recently trying to flash the google coral dev board.

1. dmesg | grep ttyUSB [ I get the expected output] 
   [ 6437.706335] usb 2-13.1: cp210x converter now attached to ttyUSB0
   [ 6437.708049] usb 2-13.1: cp210x converter now attached to ttyUSB1
2. screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
   Screen goes back (blinking cursor)

But after I power up the dev board, no welcome message or anything comes up on the console, it just remains blank. I am not sure what the issue is. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have reached out to us privately via the coral-support channel and this issue was resolved. 
Just wanted to add in for other to reference, this is a rarer issue that we've faced, but we were able to get the board working again after a reflash with an sdcard recovery image.

Comment: Thank you for the support! Yes, sdcard recovery image method worked perfectly well.