# Unable to connect to dev board after the first boot

Tags: google-coral

I went through the setup procedures from the Doc and was able to get the device up and running but when I try to connect to the device the next day no devices show up.

Below are the steps I try:

1. I connected the usb type c power port and the OTG data port.
2. I ran `mdt devices` and `fastboot devices`, both commands show no device
3. Then I try to went through the whole procedure again and I got the same result as discuss in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62021192/nothing-shows-up-on-console-after-powering-coral-dev-board) post.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For those who have experienced the same problem:

make sure that the TPU is connected to the board. If it is not connected when you power up the board the LED will not light up.

I accidentally disconnect it when I try to put the board in a 3D printed case.

I was able to fix this issue by making sure that the board is connected to the TPU.